# Fast plot of pixelated image in plotly

Tags: python, css, image, plotly, jupyter-lab

I use plotly to visualize images with additional data in python jupyter notebooks (jupyter-lab).

I have currently three implementations, two show the desired result but are slow, the third one is fast but shows blurry images.

Especially when it comes to investigating behavior of image-processing networks, I need to see each pixel of the image. CSS already supports that simply by setting this style parameter

`style="image-rendering: pixelated;"`

I would like to include this as part of my plotly visualizations.

---

These are the options I know of. (One and two seem to do something similar under the hood)

1. `plotly.express.imshow`
2. since I work with grayscale images, I can also use `HeatMap` to plot images
3. encoding the image to base64 and setting it in go.Layout.images `f"data:image/png;base64,{base64.b64encode(res)}"`

Again: The option 1 and 2 work, **but are very slow** compared to option 3. (Edit: **>30x slower** for 1024x1024 image, see below) This impacts the development when doing this on a regular basis. The option 3 is nice, but has the problem that png images are blurred.

Here an example run in jupyter lab

```py
import cv2
import base64
import numpy as np
from plotly import graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from IPython.display import display, HTML

image = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(50, 50))

display(px.imshow(image))

_, res = cv2.imencode(".png", image * 255)
data = b"data:image/png;base64," + base64.b64encode(res)

fig = go.FigureWidget()
n_y_pixel, n_x_pixel = image.shape[:2]
layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(range=(0, n_x_pixel)),
    yaxis=dict(range=(n_y_pixel, 0), scaleanchor="x", scaleratio=1.0),
    images=[
        dict(
            source=data.decode(),
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            x=-0.5,
            y=-0.5,
            sizex=n_x_pixel,
            sizey=n_y_pixel,
        )
    ],
)
fig.update_layout(layout)
display(fig)
```

| Option 1: | Option 3: | Option 3 + manually hacking afterwards: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: plotly express image without blur] | [image: layout image, fast but unnecessarily blurry] | [image] |

The manual hack is basically executing this in a separate cell afterwards. (It is not reliable, so you may want to reload the window and only plot option two)

`display(HTML("<script>var imgElement = document.querySelector('image'); imgElement.style.imageRendering = 'pixelated'; </script>"))`

**My goal** is to have option 3 with pixelated accuracy, without the need to hack it every time I plot something in every notebook. I don't see how this is possible, or even if this is simply a feature request to plotly.

Things I tried

- I couldn't find a parameter in `Layout` where I could override the style
- running the `display(HTML(` hack in my plot function before the figure has no impact. This would be necessary if want to integrate it into my plotting function

Thanks for any help!

---

I am using

- python 3.10
- plotly 5.6.0

---

Time measurements with an image of size (1024, 1024) in my browser
(simply using the code above, but using `image = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(1024, 1024))`. plotly v5.15.0; chrome 114.0.5735.198, jupyter lab 3.3.2

- 6.7 seconds using `px.imshow`
- 0.2 seconds using my method with base64

Comment: Plotly(.py) uses plotly.js as the plotting backend, plotly 5.6.0 embed plotly.js 2.9.0. I suggest you update plotly to v[5.15.0](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#5150---2023-06-08) (plotly.js 2.24.1), so you can benefit from these PR ([6565](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/6565) and [6574](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/6574)), which improve heatmap rendering performances. 6574 does that precisely by drawing one pixel per brick and set `image-rendering: pixelated;` when possible (linear axes, no gaps, etc.) and if browser supports it.

Comment: It will make option 1 and 2 (which uses `go.Heatmap()`) faster, with the css rule you need already applied.

Comment: I tried it out, but it is still much slower than my implementation. I updated to v5.15.0.

Comment: I tried it out plotting a image of size (1024, 1024). In my browser it took over 6 seconds until the image was shown in the cell. With my method it took much less than a second.

Comment: Well, in one case, you are plotting a colored heatmap from a single channel array, with full interactions, and in the other case you are just adding a raw image to the layout. The thing is that `px.imshow` here builds a continuous colorscale and maps scalar data to colors (single channel array to rgba ->1024*1024 ops, data grows significantly before plotly.js does the actual rendering). To make the comparison fair, use `px.imshow(image, binary_string=True)`, so that the image data are rescaled and encoded as uint8 before being passed to plotly.js as a b64 PNG string.

Comment: This is roughly equivalent to the layout image option, with the benefit of having a real trace plotted (ie. with interactions). But note that with `binary_string=True` px.imshow plots an image trace, not a heatmap trace (so you might have to add the image-rendering rule in that case).

Comment: That did the job! Thank you @EricLavault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EricLavault pointed out, `binary_string=True` does the job.

```
import plotly.express as px

px.imshow(image, binary_string=True)
```

This shows a 2D `image` (no-color) as a grayscale image including the pixelated effect, including a massive speedup